# How to add alias to alias_method_chain in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alias, alias-method-chain

I have an alias method as:

```
alias :is_animal , :is_animal?
```

I am trying to declare an alias method chain for the above methods:

```
alias_method_chain :is_animal, :with_fourlegs

alias_method_chain :is_animal?, :with_fourlegs
```

Is there any better way that I can use alias for alias method chain?

P.S: I rather not like to declare alias method chain twice for the same alias method.

Comment: Can you give me the Example so what you wanna create!!!

Comment: I am here bound to define alias_method_chain for 2 times...
One with "is_animal" and one with "is_animal?"

Instead is there any way that I can give alias to alias_method_chain

something like

alias_method_chain :is_animal, :with_fourlegs
alias :is_animal is_animal?

I wouldnt like to declare alias method chain twice.